# Retrive Roles name for collection of users in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, parameters, laravel-5

i want to pass users role to blade .

Usercontroller :

```
    public function index(){

    $users  = User::with('roles')->paginate(10);
    foreach ($users as $user ) {
       echo ( !$user->roles->isEmpty() ? $user->roles->name : 'No Role' );
    }
}
```

Create_role_table_migration:

```
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name', 45);
        $table->string('lable', 45);
        $table->timestamps() ;
    });
```

errors i get :

> ErrorException in UsersController.php line 23:
>    Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name

whats wrong with the "name" i trying to get ?

---

ps : when i change :

```
           echo ( !$user->roles->isEmpty() ? $user->roles->name : 'No Role' );
```

to :

```
           echo ( !$user->roles->isEmpty() ? $user->roles : 'No Role' );
```

this results will shown:

> No Role
>
> ---
>
> [{"id":11,"name":"User","lable":"A standard user that can have a licence assig","created_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","updated_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","pivot":{"user_id":103,"role_id":11}}]
>
> ---
>
> No Role
>
> ---
>
> No Role
>
> ---
>
> [{"id":8,"name":"FinancialAndOfficial Manager","lable":"Able to manage the company that the Financial","created_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","updated_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","pivot":{"user_id":106,"role_id":8}}]
>
> ---
>
> No Role
>
> ---
>
> [{"id":4,"name":"QalityControl Manager","lable":"Able to manage the company that the QalityCon","created_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","updated_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","pivot":{"user_id":108,"role_id":4}}]
>
> ---
>
> [{"id":11,"name":"User","lable":"A standard user that can have a licence assig","created_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","updated_at":"2016-09-05 18:36:53","pivot":{"user_id":109,"role_id":11}}]
>
> ---
>
> No Role
>
> ---
>
> No Role

but i just try to fetch 'name' from above rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution by myself :

i must use :

```
 user->roles->first()->name
```

instead of :

```
user->roles->->name
```

cause "user->roles" return a collection and i must use collection method before trying to get object properties

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `roles` is empty and if it is, you're trying to get property. So, change code to this:

```
$user->roles->isEmpty() ? 'No Role' : $user->roles->name
```

Comment: tnx alexey , it was my wrong in writing , it was correct in the code. i edit my question . so the problem is still alive . have you any idea about it ?

Comment: @user3634011, you didn't edited the code. Now it says `added 1 character in body`.

Comment: @user3634011 i edited it ، i put a not operator in the first and it was exactly wat Alexey said