# I'm using Laravel with Laratrust, How to print a role that's attached to an account?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laratrust

In my home page, I can print the name and email of a logged account using: 
`{{ Auth::user()->name }}`
`{{ Auth::user()->email }}`

but when i want to print the role that attached to the account using this:
`{{ Auth::user()->roles }}`

it prints a collection of keys and values of all the data in the table instead, like this:
`[{"id":3,"name":"mahasiswa","display_name":"Mahasiswa","description":"Mahasiswa","created_at":"2021-03-22T13:09:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-22T13:09:14.000000Z","pivot":{"user_id":4,"role_id":3,"user_type":"App\\Models\\User"}}]`

I just want to extract the name or display_name.

So, i'm using `{{ Auth::user()->roles->where('name')->first() }}` but it still shows the same collection but without the "[]" brackets.

Comment: You may try this `{{ Auth::user()->roles->get(['name']) }}`

Comment: yes, it does, i just had to specify the key name after roles->first(), so roles->first()->display_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys! I appreciated it.

But I just found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357511/15471776

So, I changed my code to `{{ Auth::user()->roles->first()->display_name }}` and it displays the role name that attached to my logged account perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should get first record then get field.

`{{ Auth::user()->roles->first()->get('name') }}`

Here is reference from docs

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-get

Comment: this prints all the roles that has column 'name' instead (i have 3 roles, and that code prints all the 3", this doesn't print role that attached to a logged account.